# Kendo UI Grid: date in the grid doesn't correspond to local timezone

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Html.Kendo().Grid and my column defined like this:

```
columns.Bound(t => t.DateTimeProperty).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DateTimeProperty<br>? DateTimeProperty : '" + @T("Common_None") + "', 'MM/dd/yyyy') #").Width(130);
```

It renders fine, but it is actually dispaying one day behind the correct day. For example: it will display 2/24/2013, but the actual date is 2/25/2013.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for a different date to be shown is the automatic conversion of the browsers and a different timezone. Please check [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides.aspx) code-library which demonstrates how to use UTC both on the server and on the client so the same date is displayed and saved.

Comment: Suppose I have a date saved as a varchar on a SQL DB in CST and it is displaying in MST when the user is in MST. I do not want it to convert to local timezone.